# Where could I find the stored procedure output?

Tags: mysql

I have a stored procedure that will show some message by select clause.

This procedure will be executed in event schedule, I want to understand where the messages will be stored.

```
drop procedure if exists sp_tt;
delimiter $$
create procedure sp_tt()
begin
    select 'message'; -- where could I find this message ?
end;
$$

drop event if exists ent_tt;
create event ent_tt on schedule every 5 second
do
begin
 call sp_tt();
end 
$$
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the procedure you can insert values into a table and later you can check values in that table

Comment: Doesn't it has any method can write the message of procedure to file ?Like to general log or error log?

Answer (score 0):

Either use an `OUT` parameter to return the value, or change the procedure into a function and use `RETURN` to return a value.